# Qml - error : module "QtMobility.location" is not installed

Tags: qt, qml

I installed Qt SDK 1.2.1. when I write a program using QtQuick and I want to use of `QtMobility.location 1.2` the following error will occur :

`module "QtMobility.location" is not installed` 
Can anyone help me ? When I install Qt  sdk , is Qt mobility installed automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to declare the following in the pro file:

1. symbian:TARGET.CAPABILITY += Location
2. MOBILITY +=location
3. As far as i remember - Qt mobility can be checked to be installed or not, check Qt SDK update manager.

Comment: I created a Qt Quick/QML project, and I don't have a .pro file. I only have a .qmlproject file. It's not like a Qt .pro file.